# Hide Inner circle in tool-tip of a Donut chart

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a fully functioning dual level pie chart with 2 categories. And, a measure to be displayed on tool-tip. But, the tool-tip also displays the inner circle when hovered over outer circle. I am trying to make the tool-tip display only that specific circle it is hovered at.

This is the chart. Here, pest and disease are 1 category and leaf spot, cut worm etc are the second one. What do i do so that outer circle doesn't display the inner circle along with it?

[image]

This is how it looks when i hover mouse over inner circle.[image]

And, this is how it looks when i hover it over the outer circle.
[image]

You can see the tool-tip shows as to what category the outer circle(category) belongs to. I just want that part to be hidden.

**PS:** I am using highcharts with this.

Comment: Which library do you use, highcahrts or d3? Recreate your example as live demo.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I added some detail and sorry for mentioning d3. I am actually using highcharts with this.

Comment: You can use [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and customise content.

Comment: That's where i am stuck at. I have been reading the documentation for hours and now i know i a bit as to how tool tip formatting works. But i am not getting idea how to proceed. @SebastianBochan

Comment: Please recrate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net